# Does the injunction blocking the Biden administration's suspension of new oil and gas leases only affect the 13 states that filed suit?

Tags: united-states, judiciary, joe-biden

A federal judge in Louisiana ruled on June 15th that President Biden cannot pause new leases for drilling on public lands. It was a suit filed by 12 states and Louisiana. According to [the NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/06/15/climate/biden-drilling-federal-land.html):

> Judge Terry A. Doughty of the United States District Court for the
> Western District of Louisiana granted a preliminary injunction Tuesday
> against the administration, saying that the power to pause offshore
> oil and gas leases “lies solely with Congress” because it was the
> legislative branch that originally made federal lands and waters
> available for leasing.
>
> Judge Doughty also ruled that 13 states that are suing the
> administration over its temporary halt to new leases “have made a
> showing that there is a substantial likelihood that President Biden
> exceeded his powers.”

My question: does this ruling only affect the 13 states? Is the suspension still applicable to a state like Colorado (not part of the suit)?

Answer (score 6):

No, the injunction is applicable nationwide. The rationale for this is addressed in the conclusion of the [memorandum ruling](https://www.courthousenews.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Ruling-on-Bidens-oil-lease-moratorium.pdf):

> The Plaintiff States have satisfied all four elements required for a
> preliminary injunction to be issued.  After considering all factors,
> this Court has determined that a preliminary injunction should be
> issued by Plaintiff States against the Government Defendants.
>
> The Court
> will now address the geographic scope.  This Court does not favor
> nationwide injunctions unless absolutely necessary.  However, it is
> necessary here because of the need for uniformity. Texas, 809 F.3d at
> 187–88.  The Agency Defendants’ lease sales are located on public lands and in offshore waters across the
> nation.  Uniformity is needed despite this Court’s reluctance to issue
> a nationwide injunction.  **Therefore, the scope of this injunction
> shall be nationwide.**

Comment: And even without that scoping, generally a Federal judge's ruling applies to their whole district, and is precedent nationwide in the absence of contrary rulings.

Comment: @WilliamWalkerIII A district court ruling is only persuasive precedent, not binding precedent. And, it wouldn't even be binding on another judge in the same judicial district until there was a final order in the case on the merits.

Comment: Worth noting that there is an ongoing debate in civil procedure jurisprudence over when injunctions that benefit non-parties are appropriate in public law cases.

Comment: @ohwilleke: Technically, _any_ precedent is only binding until a judge disagrees with it.

Comment: @Vikki Not really. Lower courts are bound and not legally permitted to disagree with higher court binding precedent. Courts not bound can decide to disagree with it.